# Learning C pointers i cant figure out why this is not working (K&R excercise 5-2)

Tags: c, pointers, strcat

Ok, so i am actually going through K&R C book (I know it is old and it has a lot of outdated stuff specially on the security side but i am just trying to do the excercises) Ive been playing with excercise 5-2 where i need to implement my own strcat with pointers. My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *Strcat(char *string1, const char *string2);

int main(void){
  char string1[100]="hello";
  char string2[100]="1234";
  printf("%s",Strcat(string1,string2));
  return 0;
}

char *Strcat (char *string1, const char *string2){
    int i=0;
    char *temp=string1;
    while(*string1){// move the pointer to find the end of the string
     ++string1;
    }
    while(*string1++=*string2++)//copy string 2 at the end of string 1
     ;
    puts(string1);//print string 1 concatenated with string 2
    return temp;//send back temp pointing to string1 for printing
}
```

My question is, why if i try to print string1 inside the function it just prints blanks? shouldnt it print the whole string?  If i print temp it is fine as it runs the print function until it finds a '\0' but when trying with string 1 it seems it is positioned in '\0' shouldnt the pointer go back to string1[0] position?. It is probably something simple but i cant figure out why this is happening...

Any help is appreciated! thanks!!!

Comment: `++string1`. You've lost the start of the original string.

Comment: Hi Kaylum! thanks for the quick reply! i see, so it was what i thought, somehow my mind kept thinking that magically the function puts will send the pointer back to the beginning of string1 but it makes sense that there is no way to know as now it believes the string1 starts at that positioned that i moved it.

Thanks again! :D

Comment: use `puts(temp);` instead, that's what temp is for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++string1` has the effect on the variable equivalent to `string1 = string1 + 1`. So by the time you try to print `string1` it no longer points to the start of the original string.

Answer (score -1):

string is not pointing to the start of the array. due to increment operations.

Answer (score -1):

You lost track of the pointer `string1` as kaylum pointed out. At the beginning you assign a temp pointer `temp` to save the original `string1` location - so that's what you need to use in your `puts` function in `Strcat` function.

```
puts(temp);
```

By the way, this three lines

```
while(*string1){// move the pointer to find the end of the string
 ++string1;
}
```

can be written as a single line:

```
while( *string1++ );
```

Comment: Thanks artm! yes, you are right! no need of the extra lines in the while, thanks for the observation! :)

Comment: `while( *string1++ );` : one more count (Past the `'\0'`)